# ImportError: cannot import name bayesflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I installed python 2.7, tensorflow and [baselines](https://github.com/openai/baselines) library. When I run `from baselines import deepq`, I get the following error message. What do I miss? I updated tensorflow. Don't know how to solve this issue.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b2d78f92f8da> in <module>()
      1 import gym
----> 2 from baselines import deepq

/home/dino/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/baselines/deepq/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from baselines.deepq import models  # noqa
      2 from baselines.deepq.build_graph import build_act, build_train  # noqa
      3 
      4 from baselines.deepq.simple import learn, load  # noqa
      5 from baselines.deepq.replay_buffer import ReplayBuffer, PrioritizedReplayBuffer  # noqa

/home/dino/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/baselines/deepq/models.py in <module>()
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 import tensorflow.contrib.layers as layers
      3 
      4 
      5 def _mlp(hiddens, inpt, num_actions, scope, reuse=False):

/home/dino/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 # Add projects here, they will show up under tf.contrib.
---> 22 from tensorflow.contrib import bayesflow
     23 from tensorflow.contrib import cloud
     24 from tensorflow.contrib import compiler

ImportError: cannot import name bayesflow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update `dask` using

```
conda update dask
```